# Change Enabled State of Button immediately on any change in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I use data binding and command binding to set the enabled state of a button, depending on whether a particular string property has a value or not. Or you might say, I have a mandatory TextBox, and I want the user to not be able to click Ok before at least 1 character has been entered.

My code does exactly that, only that the enabled state of the button is not updated before the TextBox is unfocused, e.g. by pressing the Tab key. I want this to happen immediately, on any change of the TextBox content. How can I achieve this? Without breaking out of MVVM, of course!

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="Gebietsmanager.GebietBearbeitenDlg.View"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gebietsmanager.GebietBearbeitenDlg"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}"
        Title="Gebiet bearbeiten" Height="110" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Margin="8,8,0,0">Name:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="8,8,8,0"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,8,0,0">
            <Button IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding Commit}">Ok</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Rollback}" Margin="8,0,0,0">Reset</Button>
            <Button IsCancel="True" Margin="8,0,0,0">Cancel</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Gebietsmanager.GebietBearbeitenDlg
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel(Gebiet gebiet)
        {
            _gebiet = gebiet;
            _gebietCopy = new Gebiet();
            Helpers.CopyPropValues(_gebietCopy, gebiet);

            Commit = new Command(
                () => Helpers.CopyPropValues(_gebiet, _gebietCopy),
                () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gebietCopy.Name));
            Rollback = new Command(DoRollback);
        }

        private readonly Gebiet _gebiet;
        private readonly Gebiet _gebietCopy;

        private void DoRollback()
        {
            Helpers.CopyPropValues(_gebietCopy, _gebiet);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _gebietCopy.Name; }
            set
            {
                if (_gebietCopy.Name != value)
                {
                    _gebietCopy.Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                }
            }
        }

        public Command Commit { get; private set; }
        public Command Rollback { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Command implementation:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Gebietsmanager
{
    public sealed class Command : ICommand
    {
        public Command(Action executeAction, Func<bool> canExecutePredicate = null)
        {
            _executeAction = executeAction;
            _canExecutePredicate = canExecutePredicate;
        }

        private readonly Action _executeAction;
        private readonly Func<bool> _canExecutePredicate;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _executeAction?.Invoke();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecutePredicate?.Invoke() ?? true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick glance, but your TextBox binding should probably be {Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your binding,

Example with MVVMLight:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Button Content="Go !" IsEnabled="{Binding IsReady}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code

```
internal class MyModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Name, ref _name, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsReady);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReady
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost feel ashamed for this easy-to-answer question. I found out myself after asking. Just wanted to make sure the answer here is the same. ;-) Thank you!